# jQuery slider does not display in jQuery tab system

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

With a friend, we are trying to do a "tab" system in jQuery. He does the tab system and I had to do an image slider with thumbnails in jQuery. 
I found a plugin called "BXslider" that answered my needs, but I have a problem with the jQuery code of my friend.

The plugin works when I put it in the first tab but when I put it in the 3rd tab, thumbnails are there but not the large images.

Here is the code of my friend to open tabs.

```
$(function() {
        $('#onglets').css('display', 'block');
        $('#onglets').click(function(event) {
            var actuel = event.target;
            if (!/li/i.test(actuel.nodeName) || actuel.className.indexOf('actif') > -1) {
                return;
            }
            $(actuel).addClass('actif').siblings().removeClass('actif');
            setDisplay();
        });
        function setDisplay() {
            var modeAffichage;
            $('#onglets li').each(function(rang) {
                modeAffichage = $(this).hasClass('actif') ? '' : 'none';
                $('.item').eq(rang).css('display', modeAffichage);
            });
        }
        setDisplay();
    });
```

With the following code, the slider does not work when I am on the third tab :

```
    <div class="item">
    <?php include('./views/ContentAjax/description.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    <?php include('./views/ContentAjax/tests.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="item">

    <div id="game-content">
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img  style="width : 200px;" src="./assets/img/assasins.png" ></li>
      <li><img  style="width : 200px;" src="./assets/img/gamerz.png" ></li>
      <li><img  style="width : 200px;" src="./assets/img/xbox.png" ></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="bx-pager">
      <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img style="width : 100px;" src="./assets/img/assasins.png" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img style="width : 100px;" src="./assets/img/gamerz.png" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img style="width : 100px;" src="./assets/img/xbox.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <script>
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
    })
    </script>
    </div>

    </div> <!-- Close <div class="item"> -->
```

And with the following code, the slider is in the first tab, and it works.

```
    <div class="item">

    <div id="game-content">
    <ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img  style="width : 200px;" src="./assets/img/assasins.png" ></li>
      <li><img  style="width : 200px;" src="./assets/img/gamerz.png" ></li>
      <li><img  style="width : 200px;" src="./assets/img/xbox.png" ></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="bx-pager">
      <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img style="width : 100px;" src="./assets/img/assasins.png" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img style="width : 100px;" src="./assets/img/gamerz.png" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img style="width : 100px;" src="./assets/img/xbox.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <script>
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
    })
    </script>
    </div>

    </div> <!-- Close <div class="item"> -->

    <div class="item">
    <?php include('./views/ContentAjax/description.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    <?php include('./views/ContentAjax/tests.php'); ?>
    </div>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem and how I can put the slider in another tab than the first tab ? Does the problem is that I use this slider (BXSlider)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was BXSlider, I don't know why, but with every other slider or jQuery plugins, it works.